# How to create an array that shows the cities of a country in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

**How to create an array that shows the cities of a country?**
**Countries and cities should be represented as action sheets**

[*This is how it should be down*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Pmu.png)

[*eg- For Canada, cities should look like this*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXyLL.png)

*My code -*

```
- (IBAction)countrySelectorTapped:(id)sender {
    NSArray *array = @[@"Canada", @"United States", @"Africa", @"europe" , @"Asia" , @"Pasific"];
    
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Countries"
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:nil
        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    
    for (NSString *title in array) {
           [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
       }
       actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
       [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (IBAction)citySelectorTapped:(id)sender {
    
    NSArray *array = @[@"British Columbia", @"Colombo"];
    
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cities"
        delegate:self
        cancelButtonTitle:nil
        destructiveButtonTitle:nil
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    
    for (NSString *title in array) {
           [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:title];
       }

       actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
       [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: What's the actual question? What's not working for you?

Comment: I want to show some cities in that country related to the given country. For Example, if you select United State I want to show Califonia, Florida, Oregon... If you select Canada I want to show Ontario, New Brunswick.

Comment: I see. Try using NSDictionary to store the mapping between countries and their cities. Remember the selected country in a property, and base the next cities selection on that. Also it's better to use UIAlertController instead of UIActionSheet. UIActionSheet is deprecated. Please try to update the code in case you have more concrete questions.

Comment: Also you are not showing cities but states/provinces . But as stated by @battlmonstr you should have dictionary  country:states

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.